# UILable Font increment with animation

Tags: ios, uilabel

I want animation for label as per link:-
http://sandbox.sodainmind.com/hijricalendar/sampleanimation/

Please click over "Click Here" button.
Then there is a animation for Date and Day.
I want exact,can anyone help me please.

Regards,
Upendra

Comment: Sir, did you try something to acheive that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Crate Date Label & Day Label
2. set all your labels with config like **yourLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;**
3. Set width , hight, font size of Date , Day, Blue Color View correspondingly to Big size.

   ```
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{


        // Put your 3rd step code here.


   } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

   }];
   ```